# Can't call angularjs function using ng-init

Tags: angularjs, html5-canvas

I have  a canvas in my html page.I am trying to call a function from my angularjs controller by default when the canvas load on html page. I can do it by usng window.onload function. But I can't pass any parameter through this way.I tried ng-init. But I am getting error .If I try ng-mouseover then it works If I keep the mouse over the canvas.But I want to call that function without any interaction of user.Just by reloading the page. I am new in angularjs. Is there any way I can do it ? Thank you.

HTML part

```
<body >

    <div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="testCtrl"  >

      <div class="flex-control-nav" >
        <div>
          <canvas ng-style="mybody" id="myCanvas" ng-init=init('myCanvas')  style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
          Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.

          </canvas>
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

angularjs part

```
var app = angular.module("demo", []);
        app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope,$http,$window) {
           $scope.temp = "";
           $scope.rows = []; // init empty array
           $scope.datainput =[];
           $scope.dataconfig =[];

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:5000/database'
            }).then(function (data){
            },function (error){
            console.log("big error");
            });



            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'Data/input.json'
            }).then(function (data){
            $scope.datainput=data.data;
            console.log($scope.datainput);
            },function (error){
            console.log("big err");
            });


            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'Data/config.json'
            }).then(function (config){
            $scope.dataconfig=config.data;
            //console.log($scope.datainput);
            },function (error){
            console.log("config error");
            });






            $scope.refresh = function(){
                location.reload();


            }


            $scope.init = function(canvasid) {
               var json=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.datainput));

               var jsonconfig=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.dataconfig));
                var n = $scope.givenNumber;

                var cheight=jsonconfig[3].value;
                var cwidth=jsonconfig[4].value;

                $scope.rows = [];
                var newx;
                var newy;

                for(var k=0;k<=1;k++){
                var c =document.getElementById(canvasid);
                    c.width=cwidth;
                    c.height=cheight;
```

This is the error when I am using ng-init

> "angular.min.js:127 TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at b.$scope.init

Comment: You could call `$scope.init('myCanvas')` directly inside of your controller function. That way it will be automatically called upon page refresh. You should remove `ng-init` from the element then

Comment: But There is a problem .I want to pass this parameter 'myCanvas' from html page.

Comment: I have tried your solution but getting the same error .```TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at b.$scope.init```

Comment: Can u check in console does jsonconfig contains any data or its empty, u can check its length by jsonconfig.length

Comment: What is `jsonconfig` supposed to be when the page just refreshed? You are setting `$scope.dataconfig` as `[]` and only load the data asynchronously. In order to make sure that the `$scope.init` is only running AFTER the asynchronous loading finishes, you'll have to put the call to `$scope.init()` inside of the `.then()` callback of the appropriate http call.

Comment: Then how come you are checking jsonconfig[3].value, if its empty.

Comment: Jsonconfig is working well @Saniya. The whole code works if I use ng-mouseover instead of ng-init. May be there is no problem of jsonconfig.

Comment: I have some hard coded value in config.json file.So no chance of empty value Saniya

Comment: @devnull69 Iam trying your approach now.

Comment: It works fine on ng-mouseover because till then data has been fetched. To achieve what you are saying you need to keep these api calls inside init only and perform the operations when you fetch the data.

Comment: Thank you saniya I am trying

Comment: If I call the ```$scope.init``` inside of the then of http call then it works. But is there not any option to sure those api call first and from my html page call the init fucntion later using ng -init?

Comment: I must have to call the init function from my html page.How to ensure those data capture first?Such that this error don't occur .

Answer (score 0):

May be I got a solution . It seems to solve my problem. Here is the code.
angular part

```
$scope.myrunner =function(canvasid){

    var flag=0;
    $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'http://localhost:5000/database'
    }).then(function (data){
    },function (error){
         console.log("big error");
    });
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'Data/input.json'
    }).then(function (data){
        $scope.datainput=data.data;
        console.log($scope.datainput);
    },function (error){
        console.log("big err");
    });

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'Data/config.json'
    }).then(function (config){
        $scope.dataconfig=config.data;
        $scope.init(canvasid);//this is the previous function 
        console.log($scope.datainput);
    },function (error){
        console.log("config error");
    });         
}

$scope.refresh = function(){
    location.reload();              
}

$scope.init = function(canvasid) {
    var json=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.datainput));
    var jsonconfig=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.dataconfig));
```

HTML part

```
<div>

      <canvas ng-style="mybody" id="myCanvas" ng-init=myrunner('myCanvas')  style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
      Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.

      </canvas>
  </div>
  <div>
    <canvas ng-style="mybody" id="myCanvas2" ng-init=myrunner('myCanvas2') style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.

    </canvas>
</div>
```